# Mpeg-dash mpd file and segments are not located on the same server. How to modify segment url?

Tags: mpeg-dash

I've generated segments files and .mpd manifest file using MP4Box. And I uploaded segments to firebase storage. Then I changed .mpd file's segment urls to firebase storage download urls. But this gives me an invalid mpd file.

.mpd file right after MP4Box generation:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- MPD file Generated with GPAC version 0.8.0-revrelease  at 2019-08-06T09:00:00.629Z-->
<MPD xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" minBufferTime="PT1.500S" type="static" mediaPresentationDuration="PT0H0M38.080S" maxSegmentDuration="PT0H0M5.005S" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:full:2011">
 <ProgramInformation moreInformationURL="http://gpac.io">
  <Title>try_1.mpd generated by GPAC</Title>
 </ProgramInformation>

 <Period duration="PT0H0M38.080S">
  <AdaptationSet segmentAlignment="true" maxWidth="1280" maxHeight="720" maxFrameRate="24000/1001" par="16:9" lang="und" startWithSAP="1">
   <ContentComponent id="1" contentType="video" />
   <ContentComponent id="2" contentType="audio" />
   <Representation id="1" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.64001F,mp4a.40.2" width="1280" height="720" frameRate="24000/1001" sar="1:1" audioSamplingRate="48000" bandwidth="1545875">
    <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:23003:3:audio_channel_configuration:2011" value="2"/>
    <SegmentList timescale="1000" duration="4000">
     <Initialization sourceURL="segment_init.mp4"/>
     <SegmentURL media="segment_1.m4s"/>
     <SegmentURL media="segment_2.m4s"/>
     <SegmentURL media="segment_3.m4s"/>
     <SegmentURL media="segment_4.m4s"/>
     <SegmentURL media="segment_5.m4s"/>
     <SegmentURL media="segment_6.m4s"/>
     <SegmentURL media="segment_7.m4s"/>
     <SegmentURL media="segment_8.m4s"/>
    </SegmentList>
   </Representation>
  </AdaptationSet>
 </Period>
</MPD>
```

.mpd file after I changed SegmentURL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- MPD file Generated with GPAC version 0.8.0-revrelease  at 2019-08-06T09:00:00.629Z-->
<MPD xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" minBufferTime="PT1.500S" type="static" mediaPresentationDuration="PT0H0M38.080S" maxSegmentDuration="PT0H0M5.005S" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:full:2011">
 <ProgramInformation moreInformationURL="http://gpac.io">
  <Title>try_1.mpd generated by GPAC</Title>
 </ProgramInformation>

 <Period duration="PT0H0M38.080S">
  <AdaptationSet segmentAlignment="true" maxWidth="1280" maxHeight="720" maxFrameRate="24000/1001" par="16:9" lang="und" startWithSAP="1">
   <ContentComponent id="1" contentType="video" />
   <ContentComponent id="2" contentType="audio" />
   <Representation id="1" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.64001F,mp4a.40.2" width="1280" height="720" frameRate="24000/1001" sar="1:1" audioSamplingRate="48000" bandwidth="1545875">
    <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:23003:3:audio_channel_configuration:2011" value="2"/>
    <SegmentList timescale="1000" duration="4000">
     <Initialization sourceURL="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/angar-fashion.appspot.com/o/dash-mpeg%2Fsegment_init.mp4?alt=media&token=52f0a3e4-8994-4538-876e-14aaa4d5ab29"/>
     <SegmentURL media="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/angar-fashion.appspot.com/o/dash-mpeg%2Fsegment_1.m4s?alt=media&token=ec1c7959-3191-4774-8187-ad4f8358a91c"/>
     <SegmentURL media="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/angar-fashion.appspot.com/o/dash-mpeg%2Fsegment_2.m4s?alt=media&token=7cca4f12-c295-45b9-b094-0115f2415c95"/>
     <SegmentURL media="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/angar-fashion.appspot.com/o/dash-mpeg%2Fsegment_3.m4s?alt=media&token=6aef7cb0-a637-4abb-9e92-c9cb44805d27"/>
     <SegmentURL media="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/angar-fashion.appspot.com/o/dash-mpeg%2Fsegment_4.m4s?alt=media&token=01df0576-401d-4b2a-8434-6f11ecdb74bf"/>
     <SegmentURL media="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/angar-fashion.appspot.com/o/dash-mpeg%2Fsegment_5.m4s?alt=media&token=2ec2692f-5178-4b74-bfa8-cf862fc7e2b4"/>
     <SegmentURL media="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/angar-fashion.appspot.com/o/dash-mpeg%2Fsegment_6.m4s?alt=media&token=a18b54ea-2e81-4ec6-8030-459a67893ff5"/>
     <SegmentURL media="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/angar-fashion.appspot.com/o/dash-mpeg%2Fsegment_7.m4s?alt=media&token=c6f820b7-f3f3-4625-b8bd-2118ff7e9635"/>
     <SegmentURL media="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/angar-fashion.appspot.com/o/dash-mpeg%2Fsegment_8.m4s?alt=media&token=99d2b5b4-1746-491d-8f85-7782e5fdf488"/>
    </SegmentList>
   </Representation>
  </AdaptationSet>
 </Period>
</MPD>
```

and I've tried BaseURL tag. But it didn't work too.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- MPD file Generated with GPAC version 0.8.0-revrelease  at 2019-08-06T09:00:00.629Z-->
<MPD xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" minBufferTime="PT1.500S" type="static" mediaPresentationDuration="PT0H0M38.080S" maxSegmentDuration="PT0H0M5.005S" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:full:2011">
 <ProgramInformation moreInformationURL="http://gpac.io">
  <Title>try_1.mpd generated by GPAC</Title>
 </ProgramInformation>
 <BaseURL>https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/angar-fashion.appspot.com/o/</BaseURL>

 <Period duration="PT0H0M38.080S">
  <AdaptationSet segmentAlignment="true" maxWidth="1280" maxHeight="720" maxFrameRate="24000/1001" par="16:9" lang="und" startWithSAP="1">
   <ContentComponent id="1" contentType="video" />
   <ContentComponent id="2" contentType="audio" />
   <Representation id="1" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.64001F,mp4a.40.2" width="1280" height="720" frameRate="24000/1001" sar="1:1" audioSamplingRate="48000" bandwidth="1545875">
    <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:23003:3:audio_channel_configuration:2011" value="2"/>
    <SegmentList timescale="1000" duration="4000">
     <Initialization sourceURL="dash-mpeg%2Fsegment_init.mp4?alt=media&token=52f0a3e4-8994-4538-876e-14aaa4d5ab29"/>
     <SegmentURL media="dash-mpeg%2Fsegment_1.m4s?alt=media&token=ec1c7959-3191-4774-8187-ad4f8358a91c"/>
     <SegmentURL media="dash-mpeg%2Fsegment_2.m4s?alt=media&token=7cca4f12-c295-45b9-b094-0115f2415c95"/>
     <SegmentURL media="dash-mpeg%2Fsegment_3.m4s?alt=media&token=6aef7cb0-a637-4abb-9e92-c9cb44805d27"/>
     <SegmentURL media="dash-mpeg%2Fsegment_4.m4s?alt=media&token=01df0576-401d-4b2a-8434-6f11ecdb74bf"/>
     <SegmentURL media="dash-mpeg%2Fsegment_5.m4s?alt=media&token=2ec2692f-5178-4b74-bfa8-cf862fc7e2b4"/>
     <SegmentURL media="dash-mpeg%2Fsegment_6.m4s?alt=media&token=a18b54ea-2e81-4ec6-8030-459a67893ff5"/>
     <SegmentURL media="dash-mpeg%2Fsegment_7.m4s?alt=media&token=c6f820b7-f3f3-4625-b8bd-2118ff7e9635"/>
     <SegmentURL media="dash-mpeg%2Fsegment_8.m4s?alt=media&token=99d2b5b4-1746-491d-8f85-7782e5fdf488"/>
    </SegmentList>
   </Representation>
  </AdaptationSet>
 </Period>
</MPD>
```

.mpd file after I changed SegmentURLs and BaseURL is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

`&` in the URL needs to be escaped as it is a control character in XML.

Replace it with `&amp;`.

Answer (score 0):

I am taking a wild guess:

This URL is probably incorrect '/' is escaped as %2F

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/angar-fashion.appspot.com/o/dash-mpeg%2Fsegment_1.m4s?alt=media&token=ec1c7959-3191-4774-8187-ad4f8358a91c
```

I would try:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/angar-fashion.appspot.com/o/dash-mpeg/segment_1.m4s?alt=media&token=ec1c7959-3191-4774-8187-ad4f8358a91c
```

If changing the URL doesn't work - I would debug your player using something like: https://www.telerik.com/fiddler